# inserting data from scene builder textfields into mysql table

Tags: java, mysql

this is my handler to add data from project fields into mysql plan table, but it throws me error of eventhandler whether i have checked the handler is sitted correctly

```
public void myPlanADDbtn(){
        connect = Database.connectDB();

        try {
            if (myPlan_PlanTexField.getText().isEmpty() || myPlan_StartDateSet.getValue() == null ||
                   myPlan_EndDateSet.getValue() == null){
                showAlert("Please Field all the blanks");
            } else {
                if (myPlan_StartDateSet.getValue().isAfter(myPlan_EndDateSet.getValue())){
                    showAlert("Invalid Date!");
                } else {


                    String insertData = "INSERT INTO plan (plan,startDate,endDate,createdDate,status,planner) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

                    prepare = connect.prepareStatement(insertData);
                    prepare.executeUpdate();
                    prepare.setString(1, myPlan_PlanTexField.getText());
                    prepare.setString(2, String.valueOf(myPlan_StartDateSet.getValue()));
                    prepare.setString(3, String.valueOf(myPlan_EndDateSet.getValue()));

                    Date date = new Date();
                    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

                    prepare.setString(4, String.valueOf(sqlDate));
                    prepare.setString(5,"Not Finished");
                    prepare.setString(6, page_userName.getText());
                    prepare.executeUpdate();


                    myPlansShowData();

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

i have checked the connection and all the handlers but it does not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the stack trace (as text formatted as code).